# Chaining groupBy on a collection?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an entity with 3 associations, 2 of which are parent/child and I want to groupBy and nest them on all 3.

Given this entity:

```
(int) 0 => object(Furniture\Model\Entity\FurnitureItem) {

        'id' => (int) 155,
        'furniture_type_id' => (int) 32,
        'country' => object(Countries\Model\Entity\Country) {
             'id' => (int) 14
        },
        'furniture_types' => object(Furniture\Model\Entity\FurnitureTypes) {
            'id' => (int) 32,
            'furniture_master_types' => 
                object(Furniture\Model\Entity\FurnitureMasterTypes) {

                    'id' => (int) 142
             },
        },
}
```

Where `FurnitureItem` belongsTo `FurnitureTypes` and `FurnitureTypes` belongsTo `FurnitureMasterTypes` as well as `FurnitureItem` belongsTo `Countries`, I want to format my results so that it's nested as such:

FurnitureMasterTypes -> FurnitureTypes -> Countries -> FurnitureItem

I've tried `$query->groupBy('furniture_types.furniture_master_types.id')` which does the first level of nesting, but this obviously changes the result set and `->groupBy('{item}.furniture_types.id')` doesn't seem to apply the second level of grouping.

There are no examples of nested group by's in the [book](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::groupBy) so wondering how to go about this?

Example of the result I want:

```
[
    '142' => [ // FurnitureMasterType
        '32' => [ // FurnitureType
           '14' => [ // Country
              object(Furniture\Model\Entity\FurnitureItem) {
                  'id' => (int) 155
              }
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Ideally, if I could restructure to include the entity level information that would be great, such as:

```
[
    object(Furniture\Model\Entity\FurnitureMasterTypes) {
        'id' => 142,
        'items' => [
            object(Furniture\Model\Entity\FurnitureTypes) {
               'id' => 32,
               'items' => [
                   object(Countries\Model\Entity\Country) {
                      'id' => 14,
                      'items' => [
                          object(Furniture\Model\Entity\FurnitureItem) {
                              'id' => (int) 155
                          }
                       ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what the final structure should look like (an example might help), but nested grouping isn't supported, you'd most likely have to group each level separately. It could also be a job for map & reduce.

Comment: @ndm - Included two examples. Something like the last one would be awesome. I realize I can probably start at the FurnitureMasterTypes level and basically reverse the contains in the query, but it would be great to see the use of the collections utility to see how this would be done at that level

Comment: Looking at the examples, that's what I would have suggested too, ie reverse the querying/containment order, as achieving this "inside-out-wrapping" in the result set would be rather tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might've actually found a way to do this, though I'm still fully confirming the structure is intact/right but it seems like it's working.

```
$query->formatResults(function($results) {
    return $results->groupBy('furniture_types.furniture_master_types.id')
        ->map(function($row) {
            return collection($row)->groupBy('furniture_types.id')
                ->map(function($row) {
                    return collection($row)->groupBy('country.id')->toArray();
                })->toArray();
        });
})->toArray();
```

The key is the `collection` call inside - which I found [here](https://github.com/lorenzo/cakephp3-examples/blob/master/src/Model/Table/CountriesTable.php).